# WPF DataGrid using convert on DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to use a converter inside a DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle?

You can see below I have put The converter inside the Text Property, even though the converter class does run (I can debug it) the original text comes back. So What am I doing wrong?

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
           <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                 Value="{Binding DataContext.Collection,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Id"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"</Setter>
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Id, Converter{StaticResource Converter}"></Setter>
       </Style>
 </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to post converter code for that.

Comment: Hi Robit, why do I need to post the code? As I know the converter is working as I using the converter else where

Comment: Answer to your question is yes it is perfectly valid to use converter in style and it does work. Issue is somewhere in your code.

Comment: So is it correct to the put the converter inside the text property? What about the DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: Yes you can use Converter there and `DisplayMemberPath` is just another property which you can obviously set in style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not the case that the text may be being converted correctly but since the combobox itemsource is bound, the display text is using the ID field since the DisplayMemberPath is set and therefore the text property is being ignored.